# History of Italian dialects?

Tags: regional, history, resources

I had an Italian professor in college who recommended me two books on the history of the development of Italy's dozens of dialects. I think they were written in the mid-20<sup>th</sup> century. Does anyone here know what those books might have been? I can't remember.

Also, are there any other good reference works on the history of Italy's dialects?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the standard works on the subject is certainly the three-volume [*Grammatica storica della lingua italiana e dei suoi dialetti*](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatica_storica_della_lingua_italiana_e_dei_suoi_dialetti) by the German philologist Gerhard Rohlfs, published in Italian by Einaudi. It is the translation of the German original, *Historische Grammatik der italienischen Sprache und ihrer Mundarten* (1949-54).

It is apparently legally available at Internet Archive ([vol. 1](https://archive.org/details/GrammaticaStoricaDellaLinguaItaliana1), [vol. 2](https://archive.org/details/GrammaticaStoricaDellaLinguaItaliana2), [vol. 3](https://archive.org/details/GrammaticaStoricaDellaLinguaItaliana3)).

Comment: I think that might've been what my Italian prof. referenced. *grazie*. Do you have any idea what the other work he referenced might have been?

Comment: @Geremia: Two other important, well received works about the history of Italian language are Bruno Migliorini's *Storia della lingua italiana* and Tullio De Mauro's *Storia linguistica dell'Italia unita* (about the period 1860-1960, more or less), but I'm not sure off the cuff about the space they give to dialects. I remember De Mauro devoting an important analysis to the very low number of people speaking “actual” Italian soon after the unification of Italy.