# Books on the evolution of Latin into Italian?

Tags: regional, history, resources, latin

What are some seminal works—for those who know Classical, Ecclesiastical, or Vulgar Latin—that discuss the transformation of Latin into Italian?

[This answer](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/8101/3378) mentions Migliorini's *Storia della lingua italiana* and Rohlfs's *Grammatica storica della lingua italiana e dei suoi dialetti*, but I am looking for a work specifically devoted to the transformation of Latin into Italian.

I'm looking for a book-length treatment along the lines of this short pamphlet: "[Italian Is Easy… If You Know Latin, and Use These Charts](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/6177)."

Comment: The pamphlet you mention is nice, but it seems to be more a short introduction to learning Italian relying on a knowledge of Latin than what you yourself are asking (if I understand it correctly).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, let's separate the comparative grammar of Italian, explained in relation to Latin and/or English - as in the pamphlet you link to - and the historical transformation of one language into another.
NB: works are sorted from the oldest to the latest.

Seminal works on the Italian grammar, explaining its Latin roots:

- Grammatica generale delle due lingue italiana e latina esposta (1837) by Luigi Annunziati and Ludovico Da Palma ([free pdf on Google Books](https://books.google.se/books?id=nLwlsOMNK1wC))
- Grammatica delle due lingue italiana e latina ad uso delle scuole (1842) by Francesco Soave ([free pdf on Google Books](https://books.google.se/books?id=e7l32jBu-A0C))
- An Italian Grammar (1863) by Girolamo Volpe ([free pdf on Google Books](https://books.google.se/books?id=xg8JAAAAQAAJ))

Seminal studies on the transformation of Italian from Latin:

- The Italian language (1941) by Mario Pei  - focuses on general linguistics (snippets on [Google Books](https://books.google.se/books?id=1SRdAAAAMAAJ); [review](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2911146))
- From Latin to Italian. An Historical Outline of the Phonology and Morphology of the Italian Language (1971) by C.H. Grandgent - focuses on phonetics (snippets on [Google Books](https://books.google.se/books?id=jvvtAAAAMAAJ); [review](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3289549))
- Italic, Latin, Italian: 600 B.C. to A.D. 1260 : texts and commentaries (1978) by Ernst Pulgram - focuses on lexicology (snippets on [Google Books](https://books.google.se/books?id=EQpdAAAAMAAJ))
- A Linguistic History Of Italian (1995, 2014) by Martin Maiden - focuses on general linguistics, grammar, and the variation of dialects (2nd edition preview on [Google Books](https://books.google.se/books?id=DwTKAwAAQBAJ))

Answer (score 3):

Another interesting book is [*Manuale di linguistica e filologia romanza*](https://www.academia.edu/34822015/Renzi_Andreose_-_Manuale_di_linguistica_e_filologia_romanza) (Il Mulino, Bologna, 2003, 3rd edition from 2009 in the link) by Lorenzo Renzi and Alvise Andreose, which covers the evolution from Latin to main Romance languages, in particular Italian. There exists a new [edition from 2015](https://www.mulino.it/isbn/9788815258861).